# Full Power in blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, hardware

I recently got a gaming laptop... an Asus GL703GE.... with an i7 8750h, 16 gigs of ram, and a GTX 1050ti... and i'm having trouble running blender in it... games run very smooth in high settings... but i feel that in blender, the full power is not being utilized, and it gets laggy... im convinced that the hardware isn't underpowered, and i checked all the power options available... can someone please help me get this sorted out... as i bought this laptop mainly for graphic designing... and it not working it's full potential kinda destroys the purpose..

The program works perfectly while navigating the cube... and also the complex structure of a space ship containing about 6000000 triangles....

It doesn't lag then... but when i start applying textures... and try uv wrapping... it gets so laggy...

PS: Please don't ask me to check the power options... i did that already

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you add information on what your scene consists of and what you are doing when it lags? Obviously CPU intensive scenes will be CPU intensive. Games are optimized. Can you navigate the viewport with the default cube fluently? Or does it only lag when merging a million cubes?

Comment: Leander is right, You want answers but in fact almost without info. Laggy? How? Did You check a CPU load during that "lag"? How many polygons was in the scene? Is the ViewPort fluent? Lags are all the time or only on some circumstances? etc etc...

Comment: @Leander Exactly.... games are optimized... can you tell me how to optimize blender... i know that the hardware is pretty capable

Comment: @JanMatys cpu doesnt run in 100%... it lags all the time... and i have about 6,000,000 triangles... and the viewport is whats lagging all the time

Comment: Is it possible to share the scene? In fact 6M is a lot but I believe there is a way to "speed up" the thing but I need to test it.

Comment: @JanMatys How do i share the scene? .... Image, or the blender file... or..???

Comment: Share here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/